# Unable to find implied volatility using calcbsimpvol function in python

Tags: python, dataframe, matrix-multiplication, finance

I have a dataset of NIFTY option price and wish to find the implied volatility for the data

```
from calcbsimpvol import calcbsimpvol

cp = np.ones(len(final_data))
P = final_data["Close"].values
S = final_data["Underlying"].values
K = final_data["Strike Price"].values
tau = (final_data["Duration"]/365).values
r = final_data["rate"].values
q = np.zeros(len(final_data))

indicators = dict(cp=cp, P=P, S=S, K=K, tau=tau, r=r, q=q)
print("Indicators: \n", indicators)

sigma = calcbsimpvol(dict(cp=cp, P=P, S=S, K=K, tau=tau, r=r, q=q))
print("Sigma: \n", sigma)
```

The Output after running above code is:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1138013,) (0,)
```

final_data is the dataframe that contains all the 1138013 points with all required parameters.

How do I solve this error?
If you have a better approach to find implied volatility using black scholes model, feel free to mention that.

Please comment if you want a drive link to the dataset if required.

Answer (score 0):

I am the maintainer of the library code.

I was able to reproduce it. The issue here is that the code assumes the price of the underlying security to be scalar (1 single number e.g. `50.5` or `np.asarray(50.5)`)

So instead of
`S = final_data["Underlying"].values`  you would something like `S = final_data["Underlying"][0]`.

Of course, that only makes sense if `final_data` contains data on options with one single underlying.
So, if you have multiple underlyings in the ?dataframe?, I would suggest to build an adapter and send only data of one underlying at a time.

Otherwise, maybe you have ticker/symbol/code column to filter by:

```
final_data = pre_final_data.loc[final_data['symbol'] == 'spy'] 
S = final_data["Underlying"].values[0]  # because now every row in "underlying" should be the same
```

for more complex filtering/selection this might be helpful:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html

Thanks for posting. I will consider this next time I work on the library.